# Can I use Google Wallet's send/request money feature with my app?

Tags: android, android-pay

Google's Android Pay API seems to be about receiving payments from clients. But I was wondering if I could direct users from my app to Google Wallet so they could send money to or request money from their friends. Like, ideally I could create an intent and set the recipient's e-mail, the amount of money, and whether they are sending or requesting as extras, and then it would open the Google Wallet app with that information already filled in.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I am interested to know if this is possible.

Comment: I think the answer is No. It's not a service with a public API.